# Trouble when joining two queries Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, union

I have a table on employees like this:

```
ENAME     JOB 
Jack      Clerk
Adam      Manager
Raphael   President
```

And my idea is to get the names that have the maximum length and the minimum length (1 per each) and in case the length is the same, take the one that goes first alphabetically (for example in the case of Jack and Adam, both with 4 characters, it would take Adam):

```
ENAME      LENGTH
Adam         4
Raphael      7
```

I couldn't find the way of doing it in one unique query so I tried to join two queries but it keeps giving me error ('ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended') and I don't know why:

```
SELECT ENAME, LENGTH(ENAME) FROM EMP
GROUP BY ENAME
HAVING LENGTH(ENAME) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ENAME)) FROM emp) 
ORDER BY ENAME
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
union all
SELECT ENAME, LENGTH(ENAME) FROM EMP
GROUP BY ENAME
HAVING LENGTH(ENAME) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(ENAME)) FROM emp) 
ORDER BY ENAME
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help. Thanks.

Comment: Got it! Will fix that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ENAME, LENGTH(ENAME) FROM EMP
GROUP BY ENAME
HAVING LENGTH(ENAME) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ENAME)) FROM emp) 
--ORDER BY 1
--FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
union 
SELECT ENAME, LENGTH(ENAME) FROM EMP
GROUP BY ENAME
HAVING LENGTH(ENAME) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(ENAME)) FROM emp) 
ORDER BY 1
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation and `union all`:

```
select min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by len(name) asc), min(len(name))
from emp
union all
select min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by len(name) desc, max(len(name))
from emp;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's rather verbose way of having a "first" aggregation function.

Comment: I did it but got this: ORA-30492: One of FIRST or LAST keywords is expected. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @jose.gp . . . Fixed.